# Dictionary magically converted to set in nosetests

Tags: python, dictionary, set, nosetests

I have created following nose test:

```
@nottest
def _test_validate_helper_eq(self, input, expected, *args, **kwargs):
    result = testedObcject.validatePrice(input, *args, **kwargs)
    eq_(result, expected)


def test_validate_price(self):
    yield self._test_validate_helper_eq, {}, {'price':'0'}
    yield self._test_validate_helper_eq, {}, {'price', -1}, 'price', -1`
```

validatePrice is a function of tested object:

```
def validatePrice(self, input, name = 'price', default_price=0):
  ...
  return validated_input
```

So I've got a test generator that produces 2 tests using `_test_validate_helper_eq` function. 
Also `_test_validate_helper_eq` function takes various number of parameters and passes it to `validatePrice`

First test PASS, but there is a problem with second one.
As you can see I am passing there additional 2 parameters, `name` and `default_price`.
This test fails with following error: `AssertionError: {'price': u'-1'} != set(['price', -1])`

It turns out that value of `expected` parameter is a `set` instead of dictionary I have defined.
I don't know if this convertion is made by nose or becaue `*args` and `**kwargs` are used.

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo in:

```
yield self._test_validate_helper_eq, {}, {'price', -1}, 'price', -1`
```

here `{'price', -1}` creates a set, you want a dict and probably meant to type `{'price': -1}`

Comment: Wow.. Now I am little bit embarassed. Such a stupid mistake. Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 2):

```py
yield self._test_validate_helper_eq, {}, {'price', -1}, 'price', -1`
#                                                ^
```

Do you mean a `:` here? `{a, b, c}` is a set literal.

Comment: Thanks for help. That was the problem.